# Undefined Local Variable or Method `f' In a view partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, partials

This seems like such a stupid, easy fix (it probably is) but I've been searching SO and other areas on the web with no luck. I'm getting an `undefined method local variable error 'f'` within my partial used in my view. I'm assuming that the "do block" is ending somehow prior to reaching the partial but I'm not 100% certain.

**Partial**

```
<% if user_admin_or_premium? %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :private, class: 'checkbox' do %>
      <%= f.check_box :private, :true %> Private Wiki?
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <%= form_for @wiki do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter Wiki Title" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :body %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 10, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter Wiki Body" %>
    </div>
    <%= render partial: "wikis/form", f: f  %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Full Error**

```
NameError in Wikis#new

undefined local variable or method `f'

<% if user_admin_or_premium? %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :private, class: 'checkbox' do %>
      <%= f.check_box :private, :true %> Private Wiki?
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please never fix the code your questions if you get a solution. This will confuse upcoming readers and defeats the purpose of this platform. (Your fix has been reverted.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Omit the `partial:` key from your render function:

`<%= render "wikis/form", f: f  %>`

Easy fix, but certainly not obvious, I've been stumped by the same issue before. The above statement is equivalent to the following:

`<%= render partial: "wikis/form", locals: { f: f }  %>`

Comment: This. Pass the f  to the partial.

Comment: Still no luck with it. I'm getting the same error message. I posted the full error message inside the original post. Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: Ended up getting it to work with your help, thank you!

Comment: for future users - follow the first line rather than the second.